# In a razor view Create link buttons that will activate a controller passing the chosen model as parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor view like the following:

```
@model WebCoreFly.Models.ViewModels.SearchFlightInfoCollList

@foreach (var fcoll in Model)
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>From @fcoll.depFlight.Location , @fcoll.depFlight.Country (@fcoll.depFlight.Airport) Leaves at: @fcoll.depFlight.Time</p>
        <p>To @fcoll.depFlight.ArriveLoc , @fcoll.depFlight.ArriveCountry (@fcoll.depFlight.ArriveAirport) arrives at: @fcoll.depFlight.ArriveTime</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>
            Tarif: @fcoll.depFlight.Tarif 
        </p>
        <a asp-action="BookingForm">Choose <a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

It is basically a list that outputs the collection of my data. Now for each item I need a link or a button that will launch a controller (that I called BookingForm and will pass to it the data of the item chosen by the user.
How can I achieve this? In html I know what I would do I would create a link and pass some info via get, but how to achieve it in a mvc context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [@Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd505040(v=vs.118))

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your link text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", fcoll)
```

Your fcoll object will be converted to a query string in the resulting URL.

Or to pass individual properties:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your link text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { fcoll.Property1, fcoll.Property2 })
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way then to style this element? How do i do that?

Comment: There is an overload with a fifth argument that allows you to specify html attributes e.g. `@Html.ActionLink("Your link text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", fcoll, new { @class = "class-name" })`

Comment: Thanks, that would be suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried:
 @Html.ActionLink("Choose", "RecieveFlightChoice", "Booking", new { fcoll.depFlight.FlightId, fcoll.retFlight.FlightId })
and it complains that anonymous types cannot have two properties with the same name

Comment: You will need to give them unique names e.g. `new { id1 = fcoll.depFlight.FlightId, id2 = fcoll.retFlight.FlightId }`. Anonymous types can infer the property names from the source property names, or you can name them explicitly.

Comment: just what i needed